# How to create an SQL query using an array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have an Array with data and I want to create an SQL statement (In which I am going to use where to where in).

I have tried to make query but no success.

SQL will be like :

```
SELECT * 
FROM documents 
WHERE category = "recruitment" 
AND sub_category in("forms") 
OR category = "onboarding" 
AND sub_category IN ("sop") 
OR category = "policies" 
AND sub_category IN("forms");
```

and Array is this :

```
{"Recruitment":["Forms"],"Onboarding":["Sop"],"Policies":["Forms"]}
```

I have tried this code :

```
foreach ($db_sub as $data=>$key){
    $query = "where document.category = ".$data." or where document.sub_category in ('".$key."')";
}
```

But getting error array to string conversion. Plz help me.

Thanks in advance.

Error :
[image]

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I am using **mysql** @jarlh

Comment: Can you share the generated query such that others could see how it looks like?

Comment: Also, please add more details about the error message itself - is this even related to MySQL, or is this a PHP error?

Comment: I am getting Array to String Conversion Error

Comment: Code is text, please post the relevant code,formatted, in the question so we can actually read it

Comment: ___Other Issue___ That query will need some bracketing. Always when using AND and OR to ensure things are processed in the order you want they must be bracketed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to concatenate a string with an array. Since your array's values are also arrays, you will have to convert them to string first. It could be done with the `join` function.

```
foreach ($db_sub as $data=>$key){
    $query = "where document.category = ".$data." or where document.sub_category in ('".join(", ", $key)."')";
}
```

Now you shouldn't get array to string conversion error.

Answer (score 0):

Use this example to create the required SQL query:

```php
$whereClause = [];
$params = [];

foreach ($db_sub as $data => $key){
    if (!is_array($key)) $key = [$key];
    $whereClause[] = '(documents.category = ? AND documents.sub_category IN (?' . str_repeat(', ?', count($key) - 1) . '))';
    $params[] = $data;
    $params = array_merge($params, $key);
}

$whereClause = !empty($whereClause) ? 'WHERE ' . implode(' OR ', $whereClause) : '';

$query = "SELECT * FROM documents $whereClause";

$sth = $pdo->prepare($query);
$sth->execute($params);
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Here variable `$pdo` is a [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) object